# How does one remove regexes that appear in latex with pattern (POL) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to create a regex to remove these patterns:

```
    type 0: any upper case char then a number (length 3-5 characters) then space (somtimes) all in parenthesis
        (FRG1)
        (POL)
        (ROU)
        (HUN)
        (GDR 2)
    type 1: (all months followed by a number in parenthesis)
        (July 15)
    type 2: imo weird patter
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 3}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO6}}$
        $)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        )^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        ^{\mathrm{IMO}}
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\mathrm{M}}$
    type 3: 
        type0 then type 2

        (POL) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$
        (GDR 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}$
        (FRG 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 3}$
        (USS 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO6}}$
        (CZS 2) $)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO}}
        (ISL 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\mathrm{M}}$
    type 4:
        two chars (two uppercase chars (or 1 uppercase char then a number) then one number then) then type 3
        II 2 (NLD 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 5}$
        II 1 (POL 2)
        C2 (ITA) 
        C2 (ITA) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}$
```

I wrote this code for it

```py
def remove_noise(markdown_content: str) -> str:
    """
    I have different 
    
    type 0: any upper case char then a number (length 3-5 characters) then space (somtimes) all in parenthesis
        (FRG1)
        (POL)
        (ROU)
        (HUN)
        (GDR 2)
    type 1: (all months followed by a number in parenthesis)
        (July 15)
    type 2: imo weird patter
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 3}$
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO6}}$
        $)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        )^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        ^{\mathrm{IMO}}
        ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\mathrm{M}}$
    type 3: 
        type0 then type 2

        (POL) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$
        (GDR 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}$
        (FRG 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 3}$
        (USS 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO6}}$
        (CZS 2) $)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
        (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO}}
        (ISL 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\mathrm{M}}$
    type 4:
        two chars (two uppercase chars (or 1 uppercase char then a number) then one number then) then type 3
        II 2 (NLD 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 5}$
        II 1 (POL 2)
        C2 (ITA) 
        C2 (ITA) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}$
    """
    # Define regex patterns for each type
    type0_pattern = r"\([A-Z]{3,5}\s*\d*\)"
    months = "(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)"
    type1_pattern = rf'\({months} \d+\)'
    # type2_pattern = r'\$?({\s?}|\$\))?(\^{\\mathrm{IMO\s*\d*}\s?\d+})\$?\s*({\s+}\^{\\mathrm{[A-Z]{1,2}}})?\$?'
    part1 = r'\$?({\s?}|\$\))?(\^{\\mathrm{IMO\s*\d*}\s?\d+})\$?'
    part2 = r'\$?{\s?}\^{\\mathrm{[A-Z]*}}\$?'
    type2_pattern = rf'\$?{part1}\s*{part2}\$?'

    type3_pattern = rf'{type0_pattern}\s+({type2_pattern})?'
    type4_pattern = rf'[A-Z]{2,3} \d?\s?{type3_pattern}'

    # Remove each type of pattern
    master_pattern = rf"{type4_pattern}|{type3_pattern}|{type2_pattern}|{type1_pattern}|{type0_pattern}"
    markdown_content = re.sub(master_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    # return markdown_content.strip()

    # Remove each type of pattern
    markdown_content = re.sub(type3_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(type4_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(type0_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(type2_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(type1_pattern, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(part1, '', markdown_content)
    markdown_content = re.sub(part2, '', markdown_content)
    # ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO6}}$\n    \n    \n    ^{\\mathrm{IMO}}
    # hack1
    # hack1 = r"\^{\\mathrm{(IMO\d*)+}}"
    hack1 = r"\$?({ })?\^{\\mathrm{(IMO\d*)+}}\$?"
    markdown_content = re.sub(hack1, '', markdown_content)
    # hack2 ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO6}}$
    # hack2 = r"\${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO6}}\$"
    hack2 = r"\$?({ })?\^{\\mathrm{(IMO\d*)+}}\$?" + part2
    markdown_content = re.sub(hack2, '', markdown_content)

    return markdown_content.strip()
```

with this unit test

```
    text1 = """
    (POL) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 04}$
    (GDR 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}$
    (FRG 2) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO} 3}$
    (USS 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO6}}$
    (CZS 2) $)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
    (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO} 2}
    (CZS 2)^{\mathrm{IMO}}
    (ISL 3) ${ }^{\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\mathrm{M}}$
    """
    # Apply the function
    cleaned_text1 = remove_noise(text1)
    print(f'{cleaned_text1=}')
```

I know it should be hard since most of it should have been able to be taken care of with `?` and OR statements. But it didn't work. Why didn't it until I added the extra hacking statements? e.g., without the hack these aren't cleaned:

```
cleaned_text1='${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO} 04}$\n    ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO}}$\n    ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO} 3}$\n    ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO6}}$\n    $)^{\\mathrm{IMO} 2}\n    ^{\\mathrm{IMO} 2}\n    ^{\\mathrm{IMO}}\n    ${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO}}{ }^{\\mathrm{M}}$'
```

Why and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hello,
I'm trying to help you but I'm not sure to understand your issue.
First, when I run it without the two "hacks". I get this output : `${ }^{\\mathrm{IMO6}}$\n    \n    \n    ^{\\mathrm{IMO}}`  e.g your comment line before the "hacks". And it seems normal to me as, no regex match this statements (for exemple, for "IMO6" to be matched you need a number between the two }} like "part1" regex sugest : `r'\$?({\s?}|\$\))?(\^{\\mathrm{IMO\s*\d*}\s?\d+})\$?' # The + after the \d`. Which output did you expect from your unit test and without hacks (I guess you want to remove this hacks) ?